What's the meaning of the `never[]` parameter type in TypeScript Handbook?
In the section on Inferring Within Conditional Types, they provide an example:
type GetReturnType<Type> = Type extends (...args: never[]) => infer Return
  ? Return
  : never;

type Num = GetReturnType<() => number>;
type Str = GetReturnType<(x: string) => string>;
type Bools = GetReturnType<(a: boolean, b: boolean) => boolean[]>;

But why did they use never[] here?

Interesting question, using any instead of never seems to work just as well? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA4hwCV4FcBOA7AKuCAebkAfFALxQHQQAewE6AJgM5QAUAdBwIaoDmjAXFE7oQAbQC6ASlLEAlugBmEVFCTA06AFBQoAflUoM2qIPQQAbsoDcmzaEhQAcsgC2pWPDUaKuFtJLE6K4ARsqENvbQAMrAKmRwiIZYOL5Ugoyx8jz+xBmoWeF2OFAAQgD2ZQA2zPGeST4snILBFZUQwgA0UMHNre3oOd19whLhQA

The short answer is that, in TypeScript, all functions that return X are assignable to (...args: never[]) => X. It's a "top type" for functions. It actually shouldn't be that way, the correct top tpe is (...args: never) => X, see ms/TS#48840 for nitty gritty. They could have used any[] or any also. They used a type that won't stop a function from matching. Does that fully address the q? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz I think yes that perfectly answers the question. Why did you delete your answer, I would've upvoted it?

My deleted answer is a work in progress (was originally a comment). If OP responds and we are all on the same page then I'll flesh it out into a full answer.

@jcalz It would be great if your answer could briefly introduce what's a "top type" first. I didn't hear about it before. And, with my limited understanding, I think you have answered my question. Feel free to write an answer at your own pace.

@NeoZoom.lua https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_type

The point of
type GetReturnType<Type> = Type extends (...args: never[]) => infer Return
  ? Return
  : never;

is to get the return type of any function whatsoever, and not to reject call signatures based on their parameter types. Any call signature you pass in as Type should be assignable to (...args: never[]) => infer Return. That is, (...args: never[]) => infer Return is meant to be a supertype of all call signatures; it should be a top type for functions.  See Alternative for "any function" ((...args: any[]) => any) without using any for more discussion on this.

Now, since you're actually throwing away the parameters of Type and you're not actually calling a function of type Type, there are a number of ways to write a function top type in TypeScript that would work for this purpose.  Here's a list of them in what I would consider descending order of preference:

(...args: never) => infer Return
(...args: any) => infer Return
(...args: any[]) => infer Return
(...args: never[]) => infer Return

Function types are contravariant in their parameter types (see Difference between Variance, Covariance, Contravariance, Bivariance and Invariance in TypeScript). That means if you want your function type to match more function types, that type's parameters have to match fewer parameter types.  Every string is a string | number, which means every (x: string | number)=>void is a (x: string)=>void and not vice versa.  Unions of functions end up looking like they take intersections of parameters (see the TS3.3 release notes for calling unions of functions). If you're looking for a top type for functions (conceptually a union of all function types), you need a bottom type for the parameters (conceptually an intersection of all parameter types).
So, what is the intersection of all possible parameter lists?  What type is assignable to every possible tuple like [a: string] and [] and [a: number, b: string], etc?  Well, the never type is assignable to all types. It's TypeScript's bottom type.  And that means (...args: never) => infer Return is the most correct function top type from a type safety perspective.
You could also use the any type for this purpose, like (...args: any) => infer Return.  The any type is intentionally unsafe and acts like a top type and a bottom type. In cases where you really don't care about a type and just want to prevent errors, you can use any.  So (...args: any) => infer Return is also perfectly acceptable if you're just inferring Return.
You could also use (...args: any[]) => infer Return, since any[] will match any possible array type.

Then there's (...args: never[]) => infer Return. The type never[] means "an array you can't index into". It is a subtype of almost every array type, but it isn't quite the intersection of every array type. It still matches just about every function, but it should behave differently when you try to call it. A function of type (...args: never) => ? should be completely uncallable, while one of type (...args: never[]) => ? should be callable with zero arguments. In actuality, TypeScript treats these types as essentially identical, which is technically incorrect but in practice doesn't cause much of a problem. See  microsoft/TypeScript#48840 for interesting bugs and weirdness surrounding these types.
But, we aren't calling the function at all here, so this is mostly academic. For the purposes of GetReturnType, never[] is just as good as never.

So apparently, I can't learn these just by reading the TypeScript handbook. But I also don't want to ask every question I'm stuck upon. Do you recommend any free online resource to complement the handbook?

I read the GitHub issues as they are filed and the release notes when new versions of TS are released. Those are free online resources but they're not particularly easy to consume. People often ask me how they can learn but I can only answer for myself, and "spend several years avidly following TypeScript" isn't necessarily useful advice for other people.
